# Errors on Itext7 using VB and .NET after installing itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter

Tags: itext7

I’m trying to run a very simple Itext7 test program using VB in .NET.  In NuGet Manager Console I  used “Install-Package itext” to install itext.8.0.2, then to fix errors installed itext7.bouncy-castle-adapter.  I now get 2 errors on this line in the code

Dim writer As New PdfWriter(outputPdfPath)

They are:
TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'iText.Bouncycastleconnector.BouncyCastleFactoryCreator' threw an exception.

And:
TypeLoadException: Method 'GetDigestAlgorithmOid' in type 'iText.Bouncycastleconnector.BouncyCastleDefaultFactory' from assembly 'itext.bouncy-castle-connector, Version=8.0.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8354ae6d2174ddca' does not have an implementation.

Restarting VB did not fix it.

Comment: In addition to the adapter you need one of the (currently) two implementations thereof, the regular BC one or the BC-FIPS one.

Comment: Hi mkl, The BouncyCastle.Cryptography package is already there.  Thanks, Steve

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the packages fixed it:
itext.8.0.2 -> itext.8.0.3
BouncyCastle.Cryptography.2.2.1 -> BouncyCastle.Cryptography.2.3.0